# Why minimize $ \Vert u_1 + u \Vert_1 $ in this Finite Element Analysis variational problem?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations, finite-element-method, variational-analysis

$\textbf{The problem reads:}$

Let $\Omega$ be bounded with $\Gamma: = \partial \Omega$ and let $g:\Gamma \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a given function. Find the function $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ with minimal $H^1$- norm which coincides with $g$ on $\Gamma$.

$\textbf{The confusion:}$

We have to minimise $ \Vert u_1 + u \Vert_1 $.

Why? The plus is strange as we are not minimising a difference.

$\textbf{The attempt:}$

Let $g$ be a restriction on the function $u_1 \in C(\bar{\Omega})$. We look thus for $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ as the following transform creates homogeneous boundary conditions:

$$w = 0 = u - u_1 \quad \text{on  } \partial \Omega$$

How does one get to minimizing the above mentioned from this?

Would you please help guide me in this. I'm a bit lost as one can see. Thank you.

Note: $\Vert \cdot \Vert_1 $ is the $H^1$- norm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, it sounds like the intent is to solve the problem

$$\arg \min_{u \in H^1,u|_\Gamma=g} \| u \|_{H^1}$$

by fixing some $u_1 \in H^1$ with $u_1|_\Gamma=g$ and then solving

$$\arg \min_{u \in H^1_0} \| u_1+u \|_{H^1}.$$

Now presumably you go from the variational problem to an inhomogeneous linear PDE with homogeneous boundary conditions, where the forcing term originates in this $u_1$ that you selected.

Comment: Thank you so very much. This was explained in a very elegant manner.